# MacOS Finder Sync Extension - Finder Context menu and icon badging problem

Tags: macos, finder, findersync

I've a main app and target finder sync extension. Finder sync extension is responsible to show Finder context menu and correct badging for items sent from main app. Sometimes it works.

But if I restart machine or application, neither Finder context menu nor icon badging is appearing at all although both main app and extensions are running. It only appears if I relaunch Finder. I tried to kill Finder sync extension and launch after launching main app but not working.